# PHFetchOptions for PHAsset in same sort order as Photos.app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, photokit

I'm using the new PHFetchOptions' sortDescriptors for getting PHAssets from the camera roll. There seem to only be two keys to sort on: creationDate and modificationDate, neither of which are the same as what you see in the Photos.app.

Am I missing something? How can we get this to work?

Comment: Did you use my answer or did you come up with another answer?  Please accept my answer if so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used the following code to get the list of smart albums which includes the "Camera Roll":

```
// get the smart albums
PHFetchResult *smartAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumRegular options:nil];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < smartAlbums.count; i++) {
    PHAssetCollection *assetCollection = smartAlbums[i];
    // Then use the following to get the photo images:
    PHFetchResult *assetsFetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:assetCollection options:nil];
    }
```

The default sort order is the existing order of assets in collections including the "Camera Roll".  Passing "nil" for options gets the default.  You can reorder the images in the camera roll and this code will reflect the changes.

Answer (score 3):

There is a super simple solution.

1. Create a fetch result without any specific options.

   ```
   // ...

   let options = PHFetchOptions()
   fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: options)

   if fetchResult.count > 0 {
     collectionView.reloadData()
   }

   // ...
   ```
2. When you try to load a certain asset just use a reversed index.

   ```
   // ...

   let reversedIndex = fetchResult.count - indexPath.item - 1
   let asset = fetchResult[reversedIndex] as! PHAsset

   // ...
   ```

That way you'll get exactly the same flow order as in the Photo.app.

Hope you find it helpful. :]

Comment: Won't work if you're observing changes `[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] registerChangeObserver...`

Comment: Why not? Just make sure you reload data on main thread from the photoLibraryDidChange: method

Comment: Hey, this solution seems wrong at some cases. I've come up with a working one by using the camera roll smart album, you might find this useful (https://github.com/Athlee/ATHKit/blob/master/Source/ATHImagePickerAssetsViewController.swift). Take a look at how `fetchResult` is set up. ;]

Although you'll have to fetch assets with reversed indices since it returns the collection where `0`th asset is the very first one in your camera roll, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Follow up on @Majotron's answer, I want to fetch all user's photos in the exact order as the `All Photos` albums in Photos app, and with only image assets.

Here is how I set up my `PHFetchOptions`:

```swift
let allPhotosOption = PHFetchOptions()
// Fetch only image asset
allPhotosOption.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)
// Get All Photos album collection
let userLibrary = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .smartAlbumUserLibrary, options: nil).firstObject
allPhotosResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: userLibrary!, options: allPhotosOption)
```

And obtain specific asset using reversed index inside your TableView/CollectionView:

```
let asset = allPhotosResult.object(at: allPhotosResult.count - indexPath.item - 1)
```

Also be careful if you're listening to photo library changes and rearrange your view accordingly. Obtain reversed index using fetch result before changes when changes are related to removal, using `.fetchResultAfterChanges` otherwise.

Here is how I handle it:

```
func photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange) {

    ... 

    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        let originalCount = fetchResult.count
        fetchResult = changes.fetchResultAfterChanges
        if changes.hasIncrementalChanges {

            guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return }

            collectionView.performBatchUpdates({

                if let removed = changes.removedIndexes, removed.count > 0 {
                    collectionView.deleteItems(at: removed.map({ IndexPath(item: originalCount - $0 - 1, section: 0) }))
                }
                if let inserted = changes.insertedIndexes, inserted.count > 0 {
                    collectionView.insertItems(at: inserted.map({ IndexPath(item: fetchResult.count - $0 - 1, section: 0) }))
                }
            })
            // Avoid deleting and reloading same index path at one update
            collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                if let changed = changes.changedIndexes, changed.count > 0 {
                    collectionView.reloadItems(at: changed.map({ IndexPath(item: fetchResult.count - $0 - 1, section: 0) }))
                }
                changes.enumerateMoves { fromIndex, toIndex in
                    collectionView.moveItem(at: IndexPath(item: fetchResult.count - $0 - 1, section: 0),
                                            to: IndexPath(item: fetchResult.count - $0 - 1, section: 0))
                }
            })

        } else {
            collectionView!.reloadData()
        }

        ...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I thought it would be useful to share a working answer.

This solves the issue that was bought up in this question `PHFetchOptions for PHAsset in same sort order as Photos.app` and working in iOS 13.

```
PHFetchOptions *allPhotosOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
PHFetchResult<PHAssetCollection *> *smartAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumUserLibrary options:nil];
PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *allPhotos = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:smartAlbums.firstObject options:allPhotosOptions];
```

That's it. Just remember that the order is the latest image/video last, so if you want to display the latest image/video first (as we needed to) then use

```
[allPhotos objectAtIndex:(allPhotos.count - 1 - indexPath.item)];
```